# Fixed positioning with Altova Stylevision

Tags: altova

How can I use fixed positioning of elements in Altova Stylevision? I.e. positioning text x inches from top and y inches from left?

Answer (score 1):

If you click on a template in your Design, named-styles will appear in Styles window.

Click on Layout box, then common subgroup and adjust left attribute value by entering desired number of inches. Do the same for top attribute