# Dynamically position layout box by XPath in Altova StyleVision

Tags: xml, altova

Similarly to this question: [Fixed positioning with Altova Stylevision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028195/fixed-positioning-with-altova-stylevision/12493924)

But I want to position dynamically with XPath expression. Which should be possible but I can't get it working.

I have this XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<strings>
    <p lp="200">first string</p>
    <p lp="300">second string</p>
</strings>
```

I added content from user defined template `/strings/p` in my Design, now I want it positioned by the "lp" attribute.

For that task I add XPath expression `/strings/p/@ld` as value to left attribute in common subgroup for layout box pointing to added template. But result is that layout box is positioned to left edge, suggesting that StyleVision considers it as 0 (zero)

I also tried this expression `/strings/p/concat(@lp,'px')` so that it evaluates to number appended by 'px', as Design is set in pixel units, but I get same result - XPath expression is evaluated to 0.
Small screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7heH.png

Can anyone assist how to position template in StyleVision by using XPath?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not layout box that needs to be positioned, but content inside layout box, whatever that is (depending on design).
In that case, dynamic (and absolute) positioning can be done by setting common positioning style attributes to XPath expression as in later example (by concatenation of unit `/strings/p/concat(@lp,'px')` as that's what program expects). And it is important to set "position" style attribute to "absolute" (which may seem like overkill demand as I initially already set that my design is in "absolute positioning mode")

After being able to see expected result, I was soon disappointed that this kind of style positioning is valid only for HTML output. Other output formats does not respect it, and I would be happy to be proven wrong.

In reality, often HTML is not desired output, but some more flexible format. And in such situations I suggest this excellent tool: [XHTML2RTF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7087/XHTML2RTF-An-HTML-to-RTF-conversion-tool-based-on), which transforms XHTML to RTF in regards to positioning elements in XHTML file. Further RTF can be converted to any common format

As conclusion, for my initial problem, using StyleVision was wrong approach. It complicated things while result was limited. For absolute positioning output from XML source I would suggest either scripting language or simple XSLT if possible, and XHTML2RTF tool afterwards